# I want to select multiple dates by dragging on the calender like

Tags: android, calendar, draggable

I came across with [android time square](https://github.com/square/android-times-square/) it helped me to select multiple dates but i cant select by dragging on it. Any suggestion of how do it?

Comment: ,do you find any solution for this problem , I am stuck at this problem from last many days .

Comment: finally I used this library [link](http://www.telerik.com/android-ui)

Comment: [link](http://www.telerik.com/android-ui/calendar)

Comment: Thank you very much !!!! but this is paid library , do you know about any other open source library